# How to use JQuery to show a div's child elements only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

So I have this jquery function that's supposed to show a class's hidden span on hover. How do i set up the function so it only shows the selected div's child span (instead of showing all the spans on the page)?

Here's my jquery function:

```
$(".thumb").hover(
    function() {
       $(".blurb").show();
    },
    function(){
       $(".blurb").hide();
    }
);
```

You can view the [jsfidde here](http://jsfiddle.net/h5x3f/1/). Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's what `this` is for!

```
$(".thumb").hover(
    function() {
       $(this).children('.blurb').show();
    },
    function(){
       $(this).children('.blurb').hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use `$(this).children()` instead of executing a global query again:

```js
$(".thumb").hover(function() {
    $(this).children().show();
}, function() {
    $(this).children().hide();
});
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h5x3f/2/**

**Note:** if you're not bothered about supporting Internet Explorer 6, you can avoid jQuery/JavaScript completely and use CSS's `:hover` pseudo-class, which will even work with JS disabled.  Or you could use a shim like [ie-7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to handle `:hover` for you.  See [this variation of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5x3f/4/) for an example.

Comment: This is a good answer. You can use a selector in children() also. So if you only wanted the first span you could do .children('span:first')

Comment: @mrtsherman: yeah, that's correct.  However, I would advise against using a selector if you don't need to - it requires parsing and each element needs to be tested against it, so it's more of a performance hog.

Answer (score 1):

Select the div first and then its children, e.g.

```
$("#mydiv").children(".blurb").show();
```

Comment: If it's the div you're hovering, then you should use `$(this)` as suggested by the others...

Answer (score 1):

here you have another solution using the 'find' function:

```
    $(".thumb").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find(".blurb").show();
        }, function() {
            $(this).find(".blurb").hide();
        }

    );
```